# Как вывести имя подмассива

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Есть массив с подмассивами

```
$massive = return [
'submassive1'=>[
   'key1'=>'name1',
   'key2'=>'name2',
],
'submassive2'=>[
   'key1'=>'name3',
   'key2'=>'name4',
],
'submassive3'=>[
   'key1'=>'name5',
   'key2'=>'name6',
],
];
```

Информация выводится через foreach ($massive as $info), и каждый ключ соответственно тоже, через $info[key1] и $info[key2]
Но также я хочу выводить и названия самих подмассивов, то есть submassive1, submassive 2 и так далее. Но я не могу понять, как это сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать непросредственно в самом foreach().

Где `$key` - название подмассива, а `$info` - сам подмассив.

```
foreach ($massive as $key => $info) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас в коде требуется убрать "return" после присвоения.

```
$massive = [
'submassive1'=>[
    'key1'=>'name1',
    'key2'=>'name2',
],
'submassive2'=>[
    'key1'=>'name3',
    'key2'=>'name4',
],
'submassive3'=>[
    'key1'=>'name5',
    'key2'=>'name6',
], ];
```

Дальше выводим имя подмассива и ключ значение во вложенном массиве:

```
foreach ($massive as $key => $podmassive) {
echo '<p>' . $key . '</p>'; // выведет submassive1 и т.д.
//а дальше выводим ключ и значение во вроженном массиве
foreach ($podmassive as $k => $v) {
    echo $k . ' = ' . $v . '</p>' ;
}}
```